# Should we disallow the Exploration tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should we disallow the [exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exploration) tag?  I don't think it's going to be very useful, since theoretically this entire Stack Exchange site is about Space Exploration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

[space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) and [exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exploration) are now considered "intrinsic" tags (applicable to all questions) and cannot be used.

Comment: status-completed then?

Answer (score 0):

The tag [satellite](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellite) should also be banned. As a significant portion of the questions asked here should be relating to satellites, the use of satellite as a tag falls under the same category.